# AngularJS + RequireJS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am using AngularJS with RequireJS.

**NEW QUESTION:** RequireJS does not load any controllers.
I am using [this tutorial](https://www.startersquad.com/angularjs-requirejs/).

**OLD QUESTION:**
RequireJS loads the main.js file, the bootstrap.min.js file and jQuery. This works good.
But it does not load angular for some reason.

I am using chrome, and in the developer tools tab "network" there are only the 3 files mentioned above loaded.

`console.log(typeof angular);` equals to `undefined`. ( I have tried that in the developer console )

There is no error message shown in the console!

**SOLUTION:** I fixed it by adding 'angular' to the `deps` array.

My `main.js` code is:
    // Require JS Configuration

```
require.config({ // Code format changed
// alias library paths
paths: {
    'jquery': '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    'domReady': '../bower_components/requirejs-domready/domReady',
    'angular': '../bower_components/angular/angular.min',
    'angular-route': '../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min',
    'ngFx': '../bower_components/ngFx/dist/ngFx.min',
    'angular-ui-router': '../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min',
    'bootstrap': '../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min'
},

// angular does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
shim: {
    'angular': {
        exports: 'angular'
    },
    'angular-route': {
        deps: [ "angular" ]
    },
    'ngFx': {
        deps: [ "angular" ]
    },
    'angular-ui-router': {
        deps: [ "angular" ]
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: [ "jquery" ]
    }
},

// Kick start application
deps: [
    './bootstrap',
    'domReady',
    'angular',
    'angular-route',
    'ngFx',
    'angular-ui-router',
    'bootstrap'
]
});
```

My `bootstrap.js` file:

```
define([
   'require',
   'angular',
   'app',
   'routes'
], function (require, ng) {
    'use strict';

    require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
        ng.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

My `app.js` file:

```
define([
    'angular',
    './controllers/index',
    './directives/index',
    './filters/index',
    './services/index'
], function (ng) {
    'use strict';

    return ng.module('app', [
        'app.services',
        'app.controllers',
        'app.filters',
        'app.directives',
        'ngFx',
        'ngRoute'
    ]).config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    });
});
```

Folder structure:

```
angular
    controllers
        index.js
        menu.js
        module.js
    directives
    filters
    services

    app.js
    bootstrap.js
    main.js
    routes.js
bower_components
    ...
```

Thank you for your help! :-)

Comment: add `'angular'` into `deps` array in after `'./bootstrap'`

Comment: You're unnecessarily declaring multiple `exports` properties for Angular. The only one you should need is for `'angular'`, get rid of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use angular.bootstrap with RequireJS. Also you should add angular to deps.
Here api reference:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: Okay, I have setup this using [this Tutorial](https://www.startersquad.com/angularjs-requirejs/) - Adding Angular to the deps worked fine. Now there is the problem, that the controllers are not beeing loaded from the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed my problems:

1. Add the dependencies to the main.js's `deps` array.
2. Twitter Bootstrap and the Bootstrap.js file were running into a name conflict. I solved this issue by renaming the `'bootstrap': '../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min'` to `'tw-bootstrap': '../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min'` and renamed all other relations.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the solution for same issue last couple of hours, dig out every possible way but  finally got the solution by Renaming angular module name **'app'** to something else i.e **'myApp'**. then it start working.

**Amended code here**

```
define([
   'require',
   'angular',
   'app',
   'routes'
], function (require, ng) {
    'use strict';

    require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
        ng.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
});
My app.js file:

define([
    'angular',
    './controllers/index',
    './directives/index',
    './filters/index',
    './services/index'
], function (ng) {
    'use strict';

    return ng.module('myApp', [
        'app.services',
        'app.controllers',
        'app.filters',
        'app.directives',
        'ngFx',
        'ngRoute'
    ]).config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    });
});
```